# How to handle the parallel request using selenium python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there any solution to handle parallel request using selenium python. I have to login a website and need to scrape the data. But when I post the request simultaneously the first request is able to get data and automate correctly, but for the second request it stops and shows 502 Bad Gateway and stops and middle of the script. Is there any solution to handle this situation.

Comment: You would have to open a second tab and make the second request there.  That's possible with Selenium.